# Kibana - dashboard to find something and display nearby records from logs

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I've configured ELK stack for our system (.NET application). It works good but in current configuration it's not convenient to search for *some text* and display results with nearby application logs in the table (for example, I want to trace how particular object was moving through functions in code).

I've made a dashboard that consists of a textbox, set of filters, a graph of events and two tables - one for search results and the second for all events.

The task I want to complete:

1) Enter the query in the search box
2) Display results in both the graph and the first table.
3) By clicking a point in the graph or a row in the table (or maybe a link in ID field) second table should display item with the same id as clicked AND all next records (up to the page limit of the table).

For now with the existing dashboard I can proceed with first two steps, but the third one is done manually by reducing the time period in the graph so that the table of events contains found record and several surrounding.

Can this be done in Kibana? Probably, I can write some javascript code to complete the task.
How could I filter the table with javascript to select a row by ID and also select PageLimit - 1 next reords?
Or another way could be to filter the table by time so that its range becomes from the time of selected event to (for example) next five minutes.

Is there any documentation with javascript API for Kibana?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is not built into kibana 3 nor the current version of kibana 4.  My suggestion would be to edit the table display to add a new link to each row.  The link could be populated with the object_id and date range (+/- 15 min, etc) and open a kibana page in a new window.

This would be based around the [Templates and Scripts](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/kibana/current/templated-and-scripted-dashboards.html) functionality.